# Issue with Google Apps Script Ui prompt method

Tags: google-apps-script, prompt

The Google Apps Script Ui [prompt method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#prompt(String,ButtonSet)) does not seem to be working for me in a specific instance and I'm not sure why. Basically, I'm just trying to add a note to a checkbox cell in Sheets through a Ui prompt. When any checkbox on a specifically named sheet gets checked (e.value === 'TRUE'), I want a prompt box to appear that will allow me to add a note to that cell. When unchecked (e.value === 'FALSE'), I want the note to be removed. Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (e.source.getSheetName() === 'School Days') {
    ui.alert('e.source is School Days'); // this alert works
    if (e.value === 'TRUE') {
      ui.alert('e.value is TRUE'); // this alert works
      var prompt = ui.prompt('Add Note', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      e.range.setNote(prompt.getResponseText());
    } else if (e.value === 'FALSE') {
      ui.alert('e.value is FALSE'); // this alert works
      e.range.clearNote();
    }
  }
};
```

Of note, all the `ui.alert('string')` methods work as expected so I can verify the code logic is working correctly. For instance, I get the alert stating 'e.value is TRUE'

[image]

but the prompt never appears afterward. This should be really simple, but it has me stumped. I've tested and verified that the prompt method works in a separate `prompt()` function

```
function prompt() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var prompt = ui.prompt('Test prompt', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
};
```

that does run...

[image]

but even though my `onEdit(e)` function is setup the same it doesn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that in your situation, you might be using ``onEdit()`` by [a simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). If it's so, it cannot use ``ui.prompt()``. You can see the error at Execution transcript at the script editor. So how about using [an installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)? For example, please rename ``onEdit(e)`` to ``myFunction(e)``, and install ``myFunction`` as the installable trigger of onEdit, and then try it again. If this was not the solution for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Looks like that worked! I suspected that it might have something to do with the onEdit() but I didn't see anything in the documentation that seem to explain why and I hadn't thought of making it an installable trigger. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved.